# How to get mongodb collection iterator?

Tags: php, mongodb, iterator

I'm connecting to mongo db like this:

```
$mongoClient = new MongoDB\Client($db_string);
```

Getting collection like this:

```
$collection = $mongoClient->selectCollection('database_name', 'collection_name');
```

And getting collection iterator like this:

```
$iterator = $collection->find();
```

However last call shoots error:

***[error]  Could not retrieve source count from demo_article: Authentication failed.***

What I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

Here:

```
  protected function initializeIterator()
  {
    $this->iterator = $this->collection->find();
    if($this->iterator instanceof Traversable) {
      echo "**Traversable!**";
    }
```

iterator is Traversable. But then, this code is called from SourcePluginBase:

```
  protected function doCount() {
    $iterator = $this->getIterator();
    if($iterator instanceof Traversable) {
      echo "**TRAVERSABLE!**";
    }else{
      echo "**NOT TRAVERSABLE!**";
    }
```

and it's not Traversable?! How can it loos that traversable status ?

Comment: Not saying that you personally do this wrong, but what is going wrong here - by the error message - is Authentication. Have you considered it may be an issue? If Yes/no why or why not?

Comment: @hakre I'm writing an migration so my source class requires iterator. So idea is to connect to DB, select collection and then get it's iterator. And if it's about authentication how come it happens when getting iterator and not i.e. at first step, when connecting to DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation for the [`MongoDB\Client`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBClient__construct/) class, the constructor does not perform the actual connection:

> A MongoDB\Driver\Manager is constructed internally. Per the Server Discovery and Monitoring specification, MongoDB\Driver\Manager::__construct() performs no I/O. Connections will be initialized on demand, when the first operation is executed.

It means that the connection will be opened only when you execute the first query. If you provided no credentials in the connection string, or if they are incorrect, then you get an "Authentication failed" error on that query.

Comment: My $db_string loosk like: mongodb://root:rootpassword@mongodb:27017/demo
(connecting to mongodb container from php container) Can I somehow get more detailed info on what's wrong so authentication fails?

Comment: @MilanG I guess the root user was created in the admin database and not demo, so you should end the string with `/admin` instead of `/demo`.

Comment: I think that admin database is system one, for storing the users. But my data is stored in demo database.

Comment: @MilanG The database in the connection string is only used for authentication, nothing else (as stated [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php)).

Comment: @Oliver, ok seems to work. But now I have different error: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to iterator_count() must implement interface Traversable, null given in iterator_count()
Is $collection->find() the right way to get collection's iterator?

Comment: @MilanG `find()` returns a [`Cursor`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php) object and you can use `foreach()` to traverse it.

Comment: @Oliver updated my question. When I collect it it is traversable (it is oblect of Cursor class), but after object is returned to doCount() it's not traversable any more?! Any idea?

Comment: Ok, figured out. initializeIterator() should return iterator and not initialize iterator variable. Unlucky method name confused me.